# How to make my item hidden until all the the animation finishes

Tags: javascript, css

I'm making a navigation bar and having problem hiding the button that shows the navigation until it's totally disappeared.

screen : https://i.stack.imgur.com/pv6wk.png

my code :

```
function show(){
    var nav = document.getElementsByClassName("navigation")[0];
    var phone_button = document.getElementsByClassName("button-phone")[0];
              
    nav.style.transform = "translateX(0)";   
    phone_button.style.opacity = "0"           
}

function hide(){
    var nav = document.getElementsByClassName("navigation")[0];
    var phone_button = document.getElementsByClassName("button-phone")[0];
    
    nav.style.transform = "translateX(-100%)";
    phone_button.style.opacity = "1"

}
```

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS code so that the viewers can test it by themselves

Comment: Please add you html and css

Comment: There is nothing that creates animation in the code you have given. Is there a transition setting somewhere or are you looking for a different effect?

Comment: Yes I was referring to transitions not animations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `z-index` property for `.navigation` instead of using `opacity` for `phone_button`. in CSS file you set `z-index:10;` for `.navigaion` class.

Besides that, it's better to set the property in one class in CSS and after clicking on `phone_button` just toggle this specific class for `navigation`

You can do like this:

```js
const btn=document.querySelector(".menuBtn");
const nav=document.querySelector('.navigation');
const closeBtn=document.querySelector('.closeBtn');

btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
  nav.classList.add('show');
})

closeBtn.addEventListener('click',function(){
  nav.classList.remove('show');
})
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.container{
  position:relative;
   display:flex;
}
.navigation{
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:100vh;
  background-color:#e45;
  transform:translateX(-100%);
  transition:transform 0.5s;
    z-index:10
}

.navigation.show{
  transform:translateX(0)
}

li{
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
}

a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
  padding:0.3rem 1rem;
  margin-top:0.5rem;
  display:block;
}

.closeBtn{
  cursor:pointer;
  color:white;
  padding:1rem;
  display:block;
  margin-left:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class='menuBtn'>click me</button>
<nav class="navigation">
  <span class="closeBtn">close</span>
  <ui>
    <li>
      <a href="#">home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">about</a>
    </li>
  </ui>
</nav>
</div>
```

With this snippet code after the user clicked on the `click me` button, the `.show` class add to `nav` item class list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [transitionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionend_event) event and hide the Button in an eventlistener

Answer (score 0):

You can use this event check this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_animationend.asp).

```
var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");

// Code for Chrome, Safari and Opera

x.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", myEndFunction);

// Standard syntax
x.addEventListener("animationend", myEndFunction);
```